# IndexOf('+') funciona porém o IndexOf('*') não está funcionando?

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

O código a seguir é uma calculadora simples que aceita dois números e aplica `+`, `*`, `-` ou `/`. e a entrada do sinal `+` está funcionando bem:

```
input = Console.ReadLine();
while (input.Contains("+"))
{
    int result;
    int plusIndex = input.IndexOf('+');
    Int32.TryParse(input.Substring(0, plusIndex), 
                out int number1);
    Int32.TryParse(input.Substring(plusIndex, input.Length - plusIndex), 
                out int number2);
    result = number1 + number2;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    input = input.Remove(plusIndex, 1);
}
```

O resultado está sempre correto, porém, o sinal `*` não está funcionando, porque `number2` é sempre `0` por algum motivo:

```
input = Console.ReadLine();
while (input.Contains("*"))
{
    int result;
    int timesIndex = input.IndexOf('*');
    Int32.TryParse(input
        .Substring(0, timesIndex), 
            out int number1);
    Int32.TryParse(input
        .Substring(timesIndex, input.Length - timesIndex), 
            out int number2);
    result = number1 * number2;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    input = input.Remove(timesIndex, 1);
}
```

Eu não entendo porque, já que o código é basicamente o mesmo.

Comment: Qual a vantagem de usar um `TryParse()` e ignorar seu retorno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resumo:

Existe um problema de lógica.
O ideal é fazer o `Substring` usando o índice do número, não do operador.

### Por que funciona em um e não em outro?

No código `input.Substring(plusIndex, input.Length - plusIndex)` é retornado "`+x`" (sendo `x` o valor informado), consequentemente o `TryParse` consegue converter em `int`.

No caso da multiplicação, no mesmo `Substring` é retornado `*x`, aí o conversor não consegue fazer a conversão para `int`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense! I was wondering why it was also working with - but not with *.

Answer (score 0):

Na linhas em que estiver escrito :

```
Int32.TryParse(input.Substring(timesIndex, input.Length - timesIndex), out int number2);
```

**Substitua por:**

```
Int32.TryParse(input.Substring(plusIndex + 1, input.Length - plusIndex - 1), out int number2);
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it!